# Installing INF files for a PnP device using devcon dp_add

Tags: windows-8, driver, inf

I'm using a BAT file to execute the following command to install my INF file to another computer:

```
devcon dp_add "linux-cdc-acm.inf"
```

It works fine with Win7 x64 but it fails in Win8 x64. The error message is:

```
Adding the specified driver package to machine failed. devcon failed.
```

I assume the INF file is correct as I can install it manually via the DeviceManager and there is no new entry  on [%windir%\inf\setupapi.dev.log]. Is there another way to install INF files to the driver store for Win8?

And another thing, is using devcon really the normal and correct way in installing INF files to client computers?

EDIT:

I got the devcon source from WDK, debugged it and found that I am getting a [ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED]. Is this failing because of the settings in Win8? What are ways to overcome this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the batch file or devcon just needed to be "run as administrator" in win8.

and test signing the catalog file for the INF file was also needed.

Comment: How did you get a catalog for that .inf file?  I was looking into creating an .msi installer for the linux-cdc-acm.inf driver, did you try anything else?

Comment: @Aaron, if you have installed WDK, there should be a [Inf2Cat.exe] binary there. I used that to create my catalog file. Refer to here (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553618(v=vs.85).aspx) for more information.

Comment: I tried the inf2cat.exe, but it complained about not finding files that were referenced in the inf file, such as usbser.sys which is in the windows directory.  Did you copy those files into the directory with the .inf or did you modify the .inf in some way to point to them?  I don't want to end up distributing those files with the driver..

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively for future reference, I was able to use WiX and DIFxApp to create a .msi installer that installs linux-cdc-acm.inf and linux.inf (RNDIS) gadget drivers.  https://github.com/ambrice/linux-gadget

Haven't been able to figure out how to create a 32 bit version from my 64 bit dev box yet, even though there's no binaries..